# как передать число как String

Tags: yaml

Есть велью в которую передается переменная к примеру 1234567890123456789, на выходе получается как float 1.234..e+18, как сделать чтоб на выходе был String.  value: !!str '{{number | quote }}' не помогает

value: '{{number | quote }}'

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1314543/edit) ваш вопрос, укажите в тегах язык программирования. Сформулируйте четко ваш вопрос. Если проблема в коде, то предоставьте [минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: В тегах только `yaml`, а в вопросе речь про какую-то переменную. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: ну в yaml можно передавать переменные, таким способом '{{var}}' , где вместо '{{var}}' подставится значение

Comment: [Точно](https://yaml.org/)? Может вы что-то еще используете кроме yaml? В самом yaml нет плейсхолдеров. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747) тоже написано, что стандарт yaml не поддерживает плейсхолдеры.